# Mash Until No Good

Tags: phrase-meaning

More than often, I will encounter the jargon "Mung"

Refer to [Mung (computer term) in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)),

> In 1960 the backronym "Mash Until No Good" was created to describe
>   Mung, and a while after it was revised to "Mung Until No Good", making
>   it one of the first recursive acronyms.[citation needed] It lived on
>   as a recursive command in the editing language TECO.[3]

The phrase "Mash Until No Good", does it mean "Crash it until only no good things left"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be wary of Wikipedia etymologies, especially those tagged "[citation needed]." Wikipedia is edited by a crowd of folks and is thus prone to folk etymology, i.e, various "just-so" stories of word origins. Backronyms are a particular kind of folk etymology, an attempt to explain the origin of a word by linking its spelling to a phrase.

(As an aside and as commentary on the accuracy of the Wikipedia entry, *MUNG* is not a recursive command in the text editor TECO. It was a command in the CCL (for Concise Command Language), the command line interpreter that served as the user interface for DEC computers, starting with the PDP-10. The *MUNG* command ran TECO on a TECO macro, a file of TECO commands. TECO command sequences were notoriously obscure and powerful, so it was easy to write hard-to-understand TECO macros that mangled the texts they were applied to, turning them into **mung**.)

***Mung*** has a history that predates by years the Wikipedia date of the 1960 for the backronym "**Mung** Until No Good." The *Historical Dictionary of American Slang* has a reference from 1948 from *Lucifer* by J H Burns:

> **Mung**. That was the Academy's name for the food they ate.

And from John E Quirks' 1962 novel *No Red Ribbons* referring to the time of World War II

> **A**: I gather her cup failed of running over.
>   **B**: Her cup was full of **mung**, if that's what you mean

So *mung* means dreck, a mess of something distasteful, and its verbified usage means to make a mess of something. The *ADHS* can cite this latter usage from 1968.

*Mash* means to pound ingredients into a pulpy substance from which one cannot discern the original constituents, so "Mash until no good" means to crush together things until the result is an undesirable mess. This is a sufficient definition of the word *mung*, but not necessarily an accurate etymology.